# Passing java-script variable to same form action php file argument

Tags: javascript, php, html

Having a html form with buttons, I wanted to pass the clicked button value (which is obtained as javascript variable 'tree') to the same form action as an argument to php script. My javascript for getting the button value is like,

```
<script>
function getVal(value)
  {
  var tree =value;      
  }
</script>
```

On form,

```
<button type="" name="btn"  value="a" onclick="getVal(this.value)">a</button> 
<button type="" name="btn"  value="b" onclick="getVal(this.value)">b</button> 
<button type="" name="btn"  value="c" onclick="getVal(this.value)">c</button>  

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Basically, I would like to do something like,

```
<form action="backend.php" **js variable as argument**  method="POST">
```

Comment: To send data to the server with a POST requet, the easiest way is to set a hidden field with the value of the button click. So create a hidden field, when the button is clicked, set the value to the field and then access the field value on the server. This will only work with primitive types though!

Comment: Why not use checkbox? With some CSS you can style it as a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. The first would be to add a hidden field to the form to send as `POST` data, and the second would be to add it to the action, which will make it a `GET` variable.

Option 1:

```
<script>
function getVal(value)
  {
    document.getElementById('buttonValue').value =  value;
  }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="btnValue" id="buttonValue" value=""/>
```

Option 2:

```
<script>
function getVal(value)
  {
    document.getElementById('myForm').action =  "backend.php?btnValue="+value;
  }
</script>

<form action="backend.php" id="myForm"  method="POST">
```

With the first option you can get the value in `PHP` using `$_POST['btnValue']` and in the second case you can use `$_GET['btnValue']`

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea @Hugo